# Send email failed conversion from string "" to type 'Boolean' is not valid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Partial Class ch5_proj4_ch5_proj4
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub EmailBtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles EmailBtn.Click
        ' insert code here
        Dim MySmtpClient As New SmtpClient()

        Dim MM As New MailMessage()
        Try

            MySmtpClient.Host = "stmp.gmail.com"
            MySmtpClient.Port = 587
            MySmtpClient.EnableSsl = True
            MySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = True
            MySmtpClient.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential()


            'mail message
            MM.To.Add(New MailAddress(TextBox2.Text, TextBox1.Text))
            Dim fromAddress As New MailAddress(TextBox4.Text, TextBox3.Text)
            MM.From = fromAddress
            MM.Subject = TextBox4.Text
            MM.IsBodyHtml = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue
            MM.Body = txtMessage.Text
            MySmtpClient.Send(MM)
            Label5.Text = "Email successfully sent."

        Catch exc As Exception
            Label5.Text = "Send email failed" + exc.Message

        End Try
        MM = Nothing
        MySmtpClient = Nothing
    End Sub
End Class
```

What am I doing wrong? Every time I do it I have an error

> "Send email failed Conversion from string "" to type 'Boolean' is not valid."

Please help.

Comment: MM.IsBodyHtml property is a boolean value, not a string (which RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue is).

Comment: how do I fix the issue,

Comment: Please include your `RadioButtonList` markup code. I think you can use `Select Case` to create Boolean value & pass it to `MM.IsBodyHtml` property.

Comment: i do not have any

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this `MM.IsBodyHtml = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue` to this `MM.IsBodyHtml = If(RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue = "True",True,False)`